# How TR = a/2 in the rectangle?

Tags: geometry

[image]

I am confused a bit about a theory.

How $TR= a/2$? is this because of parallel line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion to you, always try to **write-down** the **given** conditions in the question.

Here, you are given with :

**OPQR is a Trapezoid** . What is trapezoid? It is a quadrilateral having two opposite sides as **parallel** and the other two sides as **non-parallel**. So, what can you conclude from this? You can simply conclude that it is **given** that **RQ** and **OP** are two parallel sides.

Now, consider the coordinates given of the points. You are given that : $$\begin{align} & Q \equiv \left(a,a \right) \\ & P \equiv \left(2a,a\right) \end{align} $$

Now, what do you have from the above coordinates? Clearly, the length of $OT \ \text{is} \ a$ and $QT = a$ and $ PT = 2a $

Now, try to consider the triangle $\bf{\triangle TOP }$ . In this triangle you have

$\bf{RQ \parallel OP }$

So, from BPT theorem (Basic Proportionality Theorem) , you have : 
$$\begin{align} & \cfrac{TR}{OT} = \cfrac{QT}{PT} \end{align} $$

You have QT = a, PT = 2a and OT = a

Therefore,

$$\begin{align} & \cfrac{TR}{a} = \cfrac{a}{2a} \\ & \require{cancel}\cfrac{TR}{a} = \cfrac{\cancel{a}}{\cancel{2a}} \\ & \boxed{TR = \cfrac{a}{2} }\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes its because of parallel lines $RQ$ and $OP$.

Hint: Basic Proportionality theorem which states that a line drawn parallel to one side of a triangle divides the other two sides proportionally.

I hope its clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is because of a parallel pair of lines - you know the lines $OP$ and $RQ$ are parallel because $OPQR$ is described as a trapezoid (and the other pair of opposite sides is clearly not parallel).

You should then be able to use the parallels to show that $TRQ$ and $TOP$ are similar triangles.